# Subir imágenes jquery y comentar

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, imagen, fopen

Tengo este sistema para subir imágenes que me gusta y funciona bien, pero quiero que se pueda comentar la foto y estoy intentando hacerlo sin base de datos, pero no consigo que se comente en la misma foto, he probado todas las combinaciones posibles:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="https://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ng-app="demo" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
            </span>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="submit()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                <span>Cancel upload</span>
            </button>
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table class="table table-striped files ng-cloak">
        <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'processing': file.$processing()}">
            <td data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
                    <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery><img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                    <span data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                        <a data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>{{file.name}}</a>
                        <a data-ng-switch-default data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
                    </span>
                    <span data-ng-switch-default>{{file.name}}</span>
                </p>
                <strong data-ng-show="file.error" class="error text-danger">{{file.error}}</strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">{{file.size | formatFileSize}}</p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending: 'in'}[file.$state()]" data-file-upload-progress="file.$progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="file.$submit()" data-ng-hide="!file.$submit || options.autoUpload" data-ng-disabled="file.$state() == 'pending' || file.$state() == 'rejected'">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-hide="!file.$cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
                <button data-ng-controller="FileDestroyController" 
 type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy" data-ng- 
   click="file.$destroy()" data-ng-hide="!file.$destroy">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>

            </td>
            <td>
            <div id="cuerpo"></div> 
   <div style="color:#039;">
  </div>
```

**comentar.php:**

```
<? $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];  
  $nam = $_POST['nam'];  
  $nam = strip_tags($nam);  
   $nam = stripslashes($nam);  
  $comentario = strip_tags($comentario);  
 $comentario = stripslashes($comentario);  
 $grabar = fopen ("com.html","a");  
 fwrite ($grabar,"<b>$nam dijo:</b> <p>$comentario</p>");  
 fclose($grabar); ?>  
 <body>  
  <p>Su comentario a sido añadido. <a href="angulars.php">Ir a la página 
principal</a></p></body>
```

JavaScript envío XHR:

```
var xmlhttp;
function load(str, url, cfunc)
 {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
  {
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true); // AQUÍ LE DECIMOS QUE VAMOS A ENVIAR LOS 
  DATOS POR POST
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form- 
 urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(str);
      }

    function metodoAjax(datos, ruta) //METODO AJAX QUE RECIBE 2 PARAMETROS, 
LOS DATOS A ENVIAR Y EL ARCHIVO QUE LOS RECIBE
{

  load(datos, ruta, function()
 { 
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
   document.getElementById("cuerpo").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
 //MOSTRAMOS LOS DATOS EN EL DIV CON ID CUERPO
    }
  });
 }
  //------------------------------------------------------------------
 function recibe(){     //FUNCION QUE SE EJECUTA CUANDO PRESIONAMOS EL BOTON 
  ENVIAR
    var dato = document.getElementById('datos').value;//OBTENEMOS LOS DATOS 
   DEL CAMPO DE TEXTO
    metodoAjax("valor="+dato+"&valor2=hola","recibe.php"); //EJECUTAMOS EL 
 METODO AJAX Y LE PSASMOS LOS DATOS, Y LE DECIMOS QUE ARCHIVO ES EL QUE 
 RECIBE LOS DATOS       
   }
```

**main.js**:

```
   $(function () {
  'use strict';

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: 'server/php/'
});

// Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    'redirect',
    window.location.href.replace(
        /\/[^\/]*$/,
        '/cors/result.html?%s'
    )
);

if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io') {
    // Demo settings:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
        url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    });
    // Upload server status check for browsers with CORS support:
    if ($.support.cors) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            type: 'HEAD'
        }).fail(function () {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger"/>')
                .text('Upload server currently unavailable - ' +
                        new Date())
                .appendTo('#fileupload');
        });
        }
        } else {
    // Load existing files:
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
    $.ajax({
        // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
        //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
        url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).always(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('fileupload-processing');
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, $.Event('done'), {result: result});
    });
     }

   });
```

Comment: Crear un txt (con php) con el nombre de la imagen (para identificar cual es el .txt correspondiente a cada imagen) y añades ahí los comentarios, quizá

Comment: ¿Te estás dando cuenta que los comentarios los estás agregando al mismo archivo llamado `com.html` y existe un formulario de comentarios global a todas las imágenes (fuera de la tabla)? ¿Cómo diferencias una imagen de otra? ¿Sólo por su nombre de archivo `{{file.name}}`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia también he probado a ponerlo dentro de la tabla...y no funciona...he puesto div, lo he quitado, ...he probado de todo... la idea es que cuando alguien suba una foto a mi web pueda dejar un comentario sin mas, por eso había pensado en comentarios sin base de datos, para no toquetear el codigo

Comment: @AndySamuel tendría que saber el nombre de la imagen?  la idea es que la suban los usuarios...

Comment: @AndySamuel , pero, ¿leíste lo que te dije primero? estás guardando todos los comentarios **en el mismo archivo**. ¿Cómo cargas su contenido desde angular?

Comment: @OscarGarcia disculpa mi ignorancia....no se como hacerlo, pensé que simplemente con incluir este sistema sencillo sin basase de datos se cargaría a la vez que la imagen y daría pie a comentar...pero ya veo que no es así

Comment: Si creas un archivo separado del HTML en el servidor y quieres cargarlo en tu página, necesitas hacerlo en el lado del cliente (si no lo incluyes en el lado del servidor). Como estás usando angular lo normal es que incluyas el código de carga en su controlador.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por responder tan rápido y por tu explicación. voy a buscar información para hacer lo que me dices y te cuento ;)

Comment: @OscarGarcia después de varias pruebas de códigos, encontré este que no me da ningún error en la pagina y carga bien la imagen, pero no el comentario ¿era esto lo que necesitaba?

Comment: Estás mezclando cosas. ¿Para qué usas angular si luego no usas su controlador ni su servicio [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)? Estás reinventando la rueda. ¿Qué versión de angular usas? ¿Podrías compartir el código del controlador? Te puedo ayudar a implementarlo correctamente.

Comment: @OscarGarcia disculpa...madre mia!! no sabia que estoy mezclando...la version es  AngularJS v1.3.15 y utilizo jQuery-File-Upload-master/angularjs.html por que puedo subir imágenes sin base datos, visualizarlas y se cargan en el servidor. Probé otros pero no quedaba igual

Comment: @OscarGarcia he puesto código main.js que por lo que he podido averiguar era lo que me pedías el código del controlador. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y perdona las molestias

Comment: Hoy no podré mirarlo hasta la noche, agregaré la etiqueta de angular a tu pregunta por si alguien puede ayudarte antes.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias !!!

Comment: @OscarGarcia buenos días, pudiste mirar código? Gracias

Comment: Hola @Susana , siento decirte que tengo mucha carga de trabajo y que en estos momentos no puedo ponerme con tu problema. En tu pregunta hay código suelto y organizarlo para crear un entorno igual al tuyo para reproducir tu problema es laborioso sin el HTML/JS/PHP completo, por lo que tengo que disponer de una ventana libre bastante grande para ponerme con ello. Si puedes compartir el código en un [gist](https://gist.github.com) o en un repositorio, me facilitaría mucho la tarea. En caso contrario es probable que hasta el lunes que viene no pueda retomar esta pregunta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia creo que te lo he puesto bien...no te preocupes, que si no puedes hasta el lunes no pasa nada, ¡faltaría mas!, encima de las molestias que te estas tomando. Gracias por tu paciencia https://gist.github.com/susana90/27449e3ac9f1f940e66bc5445336ccc5

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia ¿Pudiste mirarlo? ¿ALguien me puede ayudar? Gracias

Comment: No, no pude probarlo, olvidé este tema. En cuanto pueda probarlo te comentaré.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias! un saludo